# Mythological/Fantasy Fiction Young Adult Novel

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, mythology

Read this book about 15 years ago or so but all I can remember about it that it was on a fictional planet. Had a map in the book that was triangular or diamond shape with the top part of the diamond too far north for the map. Can't remember too much about the plot of the characters but there were 4 main gods/deities and each one controlled a corner of the island. Can't really find much googling with that info only, hoping someone might recall the book with more details.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Answer (score 2):

Could it be "Enigma: Planet of Gods" by David Crane? Published December 2011 or so, but memory can be a tricky thing.

> 3,500 A.D. Thanks to the revolutionary gravity wings technology,
>   mankind was finally able to leave the confines of the Earth’s solar
>   system and seek out earth type planets capable of supporting human
>   life. Professor Peter Blackwood, a former soldier, planetary explorer
>   and teacher is a citizen of a powerful interstellar Confederation.
>   Deciding to retire from decades of working in space and confronting
>   hostile alien environments, he seeks a well-deserved retirement on an
>   exotic planet of New Caledonia, where he plans to settle down and
>   start a family. But on the way to his new home a mysterious energy
>   cloud snatches him from his hyperspace tunnel, takes control of his
>   ship and throws him into another part of the galaxy where he is forced
>   to land on an alien planet many light years away from home. The alien
>   planet to Blackwood’s surprise does contain life, an intelligent human
>   life. Saved from native predators by an enigmatic young female with
>   godlike powers, he learns that humans on planet Enigma are all
>   descendants of the original crews of starships forced to land on this
>   planet by the red cloud centuries ago. And on Enigma human beings are
>   divided into commoners and powerful overlords, humans with immense
>   powers of creation and destruction. Blackwood’s arrival was foretold
>   by an ancient prophecy. Forced into a dangerous sociopolitical game by
>   a powerful alien intelligence, Blackwood has no choice but to
>   transform himself from a scientist into a revolutionary. With millions
>   of innocent lives at stake failure is not an option.
>
> Source: [AuthorHouse overview](https://www.authorhouse.co.uk/Bookstore/BookDetail.aspx?Book=351384)

It could also be The Age of the Five by Trudi Canavan. The books in the series are *Priestess of the White*, *Last of the Wilds* and *Voice of the Gods*.

[TVTropes describes the series](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheAgeOfTheFive) as follows:

> The series takes place in a continent named Ithania. The Northern
>   Ithania worships five gods collectively known as the Five, the only
>   survivors of a war of the gods. The five gods of the Southern Ithania
>   are claimed to be false and this leads to eventual conflict.
>
> The Five
>   have chosen five humans as their representatives in the world. These
>   five people are called the White and granted extraordinary powers by
>   the gods. Auraya, the main character, is the last of the Five to be
>   chosen. She tries to get adjusted to her new position, starting as a
>   diplomat. During the series she discovers her innate magic is stronger
>   than it was thought to be and goes forth unearthing secrets that have
>   been resting for a very long time.

Comment: Could you post the maps?